# NPM Intellij IDEA configuration for Angular 2 proxy

Tags: angular, intellij-idea, npm, proxy

I would like to configure Intellij IDEA to run 'on click' npm Angular 2 conf with proxy as argument. I can do it via terminal by command `ng serve --proxy-config proxy.conf.json` but more easily would by configuration done via Intellij. When I paste my argument in input, I get only `ng serve "proxy.conf.json`.
What is wrong with this?

[image: My current configuration]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, so one of the solutions is to add new script to package.json under `scripts` like   "local-run-with-proxy": "ng serve --proxy-config proxy.conf.json". Then create NPM configuration with a paramater `scripts` as local-run-with-proxy.

Answer (score 0):

I've got the same problem with IntelliJ. For some reason (I think it comes on how *npm* adds arguments) you need to add double hiphen at the arguments line before your entries, something like this:

[image]